# Is there any way to draw box outside margin?

Tags: xetex, luatex, boxes, tcolorbox

I am looking to create a box outside page margin with some text in it. Is there any way to manually position the box. I want desire output as follows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Comment: Yes, there is, but we need more information. What is the number inside the box? The page? The chapter? Something fixed? Which documentclass are you using? Could you please add a minimal but compilable example of what you tried so far?

Comment: It is a page number, I'm using \documentclass{article}

Comment: I'm fond of everypage and tikzpagenodes.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384008/margins-around-tikz-frame/384023?r=SearchResults&s=1|64.5190#384023  for example.

Comment: \marginpar is the simple method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP does not make it clear if the box is set relative to the paper dimensions, or relative to some nearby text.  So, here, I show both approaches:

1. With `\atxy`, it is specified (for this page only) relative to the upper left paper dimension.  (based on my answer at [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831))
2. With `\marginpar`, it is specified relative to nearby text.

If it is desired to use option 1 on **every** page, just change `\AddThisPageHook` to `\AddEveryPageHook` in the definition of `\atxy`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\atxy{6.77in}{2in}{\fbox{\textcolor{black}{\thepage}}}
\lipsum[1]
Now here it is relative to this paragraph.%
  \marginpar{\color{red}\fbox{\textcolor{black}{\thepage}}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are packages for assorted fancy page layout effects but you can always place any box anywhere by hiding its width, for example in a zero-sized picture environemnt.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@oddhead{\hfill\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(10,-50){\fbox{\thepage}}\end{picture}}
\makeatother
\def\zz{One two three four five. }
\def\zzz{\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz Red yellow blue green black white. \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi}: \zz}

\begin{document}

\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz

\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz
\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz\zzz

\end{document}
```