# How can I persuade fancyhdr that my headers have zero height?

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm putting my headers in the outer margins where they shouldn't take up any vertical space.  I though to achieve this by using `\vbox to 0pt{...}`, but `fancyhdr` isn't buying.  Here is the error message:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
Make it at least 15.60004pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

I have no idea where this figure of 15.60004pt is coming from or how to write the header in such a way as not to take up any vertical space.  MWE enclosed; the key macro is `\nrlefthead`.  (The example is not quite minimal, but replacing all the named lengths with literal lengths would make it hard to read.)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\newdimen\blockwidth
\newdimen\blockheight

\blockwidth=120mm
\blockheight=220mm

\usepackage{etex}

\usepackage[twoside,top=10mm,body={\blockwidth,\blockheight}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nrlefthead}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\newdimen\nrheaddrop
\nrheaddrop=1.5in

\newdimen\nrleftheadrightmargin
\setlength\nrleftheadrightmargin{-20mm}

\newdimen\myheadwidth
\setlength{\myheadwidth}{180pt}

\newcommand\nrlefthead{%
  \vbox to 0pt{\vspace*{\nrheaddrop}%
               \llap{\parbox{\myheadwidth}%
                         {\raggedright\noindent\itshape
                         \nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
                         \hspace*{\nrleftheadrightmargin}}%
               \vss}}


\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{An innocuous title}

\lipsum[23-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\usepackage{etex}` (depending which other packages are loaded it either does nothing useful or does harm)

Comment: You can also use \raisebox.  For really fancy headers, I use the everypage package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384008/margins-around-tikz-frame/384023?r=SearchResults&s=2|38.8729#384023).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `\vbox` if you don't know about it.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\newdimen\blockwidth
\newdimen\blockheight

\blockwidth=120mm
\blockheight=220mm

\usepackage[twoside,top=10mm,body={\blockwidth,\blockheight}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nrlefthead}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\newdimen\nrheaddrop
\nrheaddrop=1.5in

\newdimen\nrleftheadrightmargin
\setlength\nrleftheadrightmargin{-20mm}

\newdimen\myheadwidth
\setlength{\myheadwidth}{180pt}

\newcommand\nrlefthead{%
  \parbox[t][0pt]{\textwidth}{%
    \vspace*{\nrheaddrop}%
    \llap{%
      \parbox[b]{\myheadwidth}{%
        \raggedright\noindent\itshape
        \nouppercase{\leftmark}%
      }%
      \hspace*{\nrleftheadrightmargin}%
    }%
  }%
}


\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{An innocuous title}

\lipsum[23-50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great!  I am an old plain \TeX hacker from way back, and I still use those commands habitually.  For my education, why did the \vbox to 0pt{...} fail?