# Customize fancyhdr footers with background

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, article

I'm trying to customize the background of footers using `fancyhdr` package.

This is what I have now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all headers/footers
    \fancyfoot[L]{
        \textcolor{green}{\rule[-4pt]{\textwidth}{15pt}}%
        \hspace{-\textwidth}%
        \textcolor{red}{\setlength{\hspace}{0.5\textwidth-20pt}\thepage}} % Left footer page number
    \fancyfoot[R]{
        \textcolor{red}{Something\setlength{\hspace}{0.5\textwidth-20pt-\widthof{Something}}}} % Right footer company
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % 2pt header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer rule
}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}


\title{Title} % Title of the assignment

\author{Author Name\\ \texttt{author@somewhere.com}}

\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit. Nulla mattis nisl eu malesuada suscipit.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Two questions:

1. How do I set the green background for the right footer only, i.e making only the **right** half of the `\textwidth` green for the **right** footer (and no background for the *left* footer)?
2. How do I programmatically set the height of the background strip so that the right footer is vertically centered within the green strip even when the size of footer changes (but still horizontal with the left footer)? At the moment, it's hardcoded.

Comment: Your first question is not clear: you want to colour the right half of \textwidth for the right footer, yet no background??

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384008/margins-around-tikz-frame/384023?r=SearchResults&s=1|64.3346#384023 useful, unless you REALLY like using fancyhdr.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, a typo in my question, I meant to say "no background for the left footer". Revised

Comment: You want  the page number towards the end of the left part and the text towards the beginning of the right footer,  both in red, and only the right footer with a background colour?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, page no. 20pt (in my example) from the center of the `\textwidth`, and the text 20pt from the same center point. And only the right footer has the background cover its half of `\textwidth` length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % Clear all headers/footers
    \fancyfoot[L]{%
 \makebox[\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-20pt][r]{\color{red}\thepage}} % Left footer page number
    \fancyfoot[R]{\colorbox{green}{\makebox[\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-6pt][l]{{}\hspace*{13pt}
        \color{red}Something}}} % Right footer company
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % 2pt header rule
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer rule
}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
    \pagestyle{plain}

\title{Title} % Title of the assignment

\author{Author Name\\ \texttt{author@somewhere.com}}

\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but could you explain why `\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-6pt` and `\hspace*{13pt}` for the right footer? I assume I need to tweak `6pt` and `13pt` if the font size of footers changes? This is the 2nd part of my question above

Comment: It doesn't depend on the font size  (in theory). `6pt` is here to takke into account the value of `\fboxsep` which is used by `\colorbox`: by default, it is 3pt  on each side. As to `\hspace{13pt}`, its value is found by trial an error: to take (again) into account the value of `\fboxsep`, I first used 20pt-3pt=17pt, but the measured result was not  the expected 20pt between the centre of the text width and the beginning of the text in the right footer, for a reason I don't understand, so I changed this value to obtain the required value.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. A further detail, is the text (and the page number) vertically centered within the `\makebox` by default? If not, how do we make it so? And does that change with font and font size?

Comment: \makebox has the height of its contents. , and `\colorbox` adds `\fboxsep` around `\makebox` in all directions, in particular above and below, so the contents is vertically centred.