# Custom Header and Footer for IEEEtran.cls

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

I'm trying to make a `.tex` template using a derivatives of `IEEEtran.cls` (it's okay to modify `IEEEtran.cls` directly if needed).

My problem is that I can't implement custom header and footer in the first (title) page, nor in the following page (everything except first title page). I need to implement it to looks like this: [download](http://jnteti.te.ugm.ac.id/icon/Template%20JNTETI_2020.docx) (this is docx format).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[transmag]{IEEEtran}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\title{Judul Makalah Jurnal dalam Bahasa Indonesia\\ (\textit{Journal Paper Title in English})}

% IEEE does not allow footnote automatic numbering, use custrom authorcounter
\newcounter{authorcounter}
\author{% <- needed to escape space
    \setcounter{authorcounter}{0}% <- needed to escape space
    Nama Penulis Pertama% <- needed to escape space
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{\stepcounter{authorcounter}\arabic{authorcounter}},
    Penulis Kedua% <- needed to escape space
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{\stepcounter{authorcounter}\arabic{authorcounter}},
    Penulis Ketiga% <- needed to escape space
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{\stepcounter{authorcounter}\arabic{authorcounter}}
}

% The paper headers
\markboth{%
    J\MakeLowercase{urnal}
    N\MakeLowercase{asional}
    T\MakeLowercase{eknik}
    E\MakeLowercase{lektro dan}
    T\MakeLowercase{eknologi}
    I\MakeLowercase{nformasi}
    $\vert$
    V\MakeLowercase{ol. nn, }
    N\MakeLowercase{o. nn, }
    F\MakeLowercase{ebruari 20nn}}%
    {}

% make the title area
\maketitle

% footnote
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Nama Institusi dari Penulis Pertama, Alamat beserta kota KODEPOS NEGARA (tlp: 0274-555 225; fax: 0274-4321982; email:penulis1@institusi.ac.auo)}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Nama Institusi dari Penulis Pertama, Alamat beserta kota KODEPOS NEGARA (tlp: 0274-555 225; fax: 0274-4321982; email:penulis1@institusi.ac.auo)}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Nama Institusi dari Penulis Pertama, Alamat beserta kota KODEPOS NEGARA (tlp: 0274-555 225; fax: 0274-4321982; email:penulis1@institusi.ac.auo)}

\end{document}
```

It seems that IEEEtran.cls are very strictive and I'm confused to understand how to manipulate it. If you have any docs about the manuals, feel free to share.

Comment: Hi, Welcome! The idea is that IEEEtran is a format for submission, and they *do not want* you to manipulate it (they will not accept any different format). If you want your personalized format, better to start from a generic format, like article or similar

Comment: You can use the everypage package or `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` to apply custom headers and footers.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for the answer. But, the point is that I think it will not be submitted to IEEE It's just happen that the conference but the one who hold the conference said that they use a format similar to IEEE. Sadly, they only gift a docx format.

Comment: @JohnKormylo would you like to try to give me an example since I'm not that familiar in tex (still figuring and learning)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384008/margins-around-tikz-frame/384023?r=SearchResults&s=2|38.9813#384023